# How long does it take to complete the review stages in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-center, application-development, application-submission

When we submit an application to the Ubuntu Software Center, how long does it take to complete the review stages? Namely,

- Pending Review
- In Review

How long (average or based on your experience) does it take to complete each of these two stages?

And does the duration of reviewing change by type of application submitted (for Python, Java, etc)? Or is it all the same?

**EDIT**

More details about my app:

- Its a commercial app (I put $2.99 as the price when submitting)
- Its a Kakuro game (but the name is "Sukaro")
- It is made in Java SE *without* using any external libraries
- Its not platform-specific (as Java is platform-independent)
- I submitted it without packaging (as I don't know how). I submitted the single .jar file
- I provided all the required information (such as screenshots, etc)

Comment: I've tagged this `canonical` to get the attention of the people who run the show. That said, I doubt you'll get a satisfying answer... the process behind reviewing and publishing apps was only finalized a few months ago, and if it's open source, the App Review Board really just got rolling a few days ago...

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards Thanks for your edits! Its a commercial app (a Kakuro game), and is the process same as with open source?

Comment: No, Canonical handles closed source, and they've been doing so in some capacity since 2010. So in that case, someone should probably be able to answer (tentatively). ;)

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards Yeah, got to try my luck! :)

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards: no need to add the `canonical` tag. Generally Canonical people are subscribed to each one's area of interest, so you already did the good thing by tagging it as `application-development`. Oh, And Canonical are not the only people who run the show, they're part of the wider Ubuntu community :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two "queues" ARB and "commercial/paid". For both the review pending stage takes the longest. This is where the submission is made into a package. If you submitted debian package source (the output of dpkg-buildpackage -S) then this stage will take a very short time. If you didn't follow instructions and submitted a binary deb the process takes MUCH longer as we have to deconstruct and subsequently reconstruct the .deb. If you submit a simple tarball, the packaging process is completely dependent on the complexity of the package.

The stages post review pending are quick. Once the app is packaged it goes to QA and once through QA (usually 24/36 hours max) then back to the developer to be listed.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I am totally new to Ubuntu application development and I don't know about Debian Packaging. So I submitted a single .jar file (I made the project in Java without any external libraries). How long do you think it will take? About a week and a half ago I submitted.

Comment: @Roshnal, could you please be more specific? E.g. what's the name of the application you submitted? Is it Free Software or commercial? The more detail in your question the easier to answer it. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPlanella I updated my question with more details. Please take a look at it..

Comment: The one other factor that determines how long it takes to move through the queue is the size of the queue itself. With limited resources and a large number of applications being submitted as straight binaries or binary debs the queue is a bit congested and is likely to get worse over time.

Comment: I also submited commercial app Skrywer on Ubuntu Software Center, and I'm in "review in progress" stage for a week. I sent output of debuild and pbuilder, but why it takes so long.

Comment: What's the different of debian package and debian package source ?