# Why my app has not been reviewed yet even if its a debian source package?

Tags: application-development, application-submission

I took part in Ubuntu App Showdown. In the upload app field, I uploaded text file in [this format](http://developer.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt).
Was that good enough or did i miss something ?

Referring another [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97272/how-long-does-it-take-to-complete-the-review-stages-in-ubuntu), i quote that answer

> "There are two "queues" ARB and "commercial/paid". For both the review
>   pending stage takes the longest. This is where the submission is made
>   into a package. If you submitted debian package source (the output of
>   dpkg-buildpackage -S) then this stage will take a very short time. If
>   you didn't follow instructions and submitted a binary deb the process
>   takes MUCH longer as we have to deconstruct and subsequently
>   reconstruct the .deb. If you submit a simple tarball, the packaging
>   process is completely dependent on the complexity of the package."

My tiny application is based on c++ and Qt (haven't used quickly which i regret now). It's already
packaged as a debian source package,and is available at the PPA and is successfully built into a binary debian package there. So it should take "very short time" unlike binary deb or tarball.

Can anyone give a rough estimate of how long it would take for completion of "pending review" state ? 
I'm really sorry for being impatient.

Comment: I have the same problem, I also made .deb file and I have PPA but I'm waiting for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Mine's been pending review for 2 weeks, 1 day now. Not sure how long it takes it total, but hopefully it gives you some indication to the review length.

Comment: Ehm, the question is already 3 weeks and 3 days old. I guess he'll beat you ;-)